# vuejs multiple v-if on one element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

sup, so I have a problem with v-if in vue.

basicly I have a v-for that loops thru array and inside that v-for I have a couple of elements with v-if

```
<button v-if="Collection.status" type="button">deactivate</button>
<button v-else type="button">activate</button>
```

but I would also like to disable "activate" buttons if a data variable (disableButton) is true. How could I do that?

Its maybe a silly question but im new to vue and i have been searching for this for to long.

Comment: Disable or hide the activate button? (your example is hiding [not rendering] it)

Comment: Basicly if "Activate" button renders and data variable is true I'd also like to disable that button @SteveHynding

Comment: Do you still want to hide/not-render the "activate" button if `Collection.status` evaluated to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      Collections: [{id: 1, status: true}, {id: 2, status: false}, {id: 3, status: true}],
      disableButton: true
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="Collection in Collections" :key="Collection.id">
      <button v-if="Collection.status" type="button" >deactivate</button>
      <button v-else :disabled="disableButton" type="button">activate</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
<button v-else type="button" disable="Collection.disableButton">activate</button>
```